# MYSQL make function with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, function

i have a problem.

I need to retrieve a value from a function with parameters who make the query dynamically.. an example:

```
  SELECT pratica.id, CalcolaValore('prodotto','campo',pratica.id)
  FROM pratica LEFT JOIN prodotto ON pratica.id_prodotto = prodotto.id
  WHERE pratica.id > 5
```

the function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcolaValore( tabella VARCHAR(30), campo VARCHAR(30), id_prodotto INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE risultato VARCHAR(255);
    SELECT campo INTO risultato
    FROM tabella
    WHERE [id] = id_prodotto
    RETURN risultato;
END
```

this is wrong.. can you help me?

Comment: For one thing [] are sqlserver  - is this question tagged correctly? Also you need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: @P.Salmon In MySQL - dynamic SQL (prepared statement) cannot be used in function or trigger.

Comment: *`SELECT campo INTO risultato`* You cannot transfer column name into the function as a parameter for value-as-name direct use. If the columns list in a table is static and unchangeable then you must create query for each possible name and execute proper query using CASE statement.

Comment: ... the same about the parameter with the name of table `tabella` - you must create separate query for each table and column pair.

Comment: OK.. i think the correct answer is: dynamic SQL (prepared statement) cannot be used in function or trigger.

Comment: @akina you can pass the result of a dynamic sql select into a user defined variable which can be returned by the function

Comment: @P.Salmon "Dynamic SQL cannot be used in a function/trigger" means that it also cannot be used in a procedure which is called in a function/trigger.

Comment: @Diamond You may solve your problem if you'll place **everything** into SP, incliding the former query. You won't execute a query which calls the function, you'll call a procedure which will prepare and execute dynamic SQL and return the rowset which you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) in a procedure. And wrap your main query around it.  It isn't the prettiest solution, but it does work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CalcolaValore`( `qry1` varchar(255), `qry2` varchar(255), tabella VARCHAR(30), campo VARCHAR(30), id_prodotto INT )
BEGIN
    SET @q = CONCAT( qry1, 
        '(',
        'SELECT ', campo, ' FROM ', tabella, ' WHERE id = ', id_prodotto ,
        ')',
        qry2
    );
    PREPARE statement FROM @q;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END
```

And then call it as :

```
CALL CalcolaValore( 
    'SELECT pra .id, ',
    'FROM pratica AS pra LEFT JOIN prodotto AS pro ON pra.id_prodotto = pro.id WHERE pra.id > 5', 
    'prodotto','campo', 'pra.id'
);
```

Also, please not the aliasses. As prodotto is used in both queries and you want to adddess the correct one.

Comment: OP needs to use the result in a query. But procedure cannot be used as data source in a query. So the solution is not applicable for OP's task.

Comment: He needs 1 value for each row in query dataset - so he needs many calls which will return many values, which must be a part of one output rowset. In your solution each obtained value will form a separate 1-column 1-row rowset.

Comment: You are right, didn't think about the fact that you cannot include that in a select query

Comment: Think about it, you could wrap the main query around the dynamic one inside the procedure, that will work.  Changed the anwser to include that

Comment: As I have said to OP in the comment to the question, "You may solve your problem if you'll place **everything** into SP, incliding the former query". I think this is more simple than your variant where you need to transfer the query code as a parameter and to replace names treated as placeholders with their actual values.